SQL - how to delete duplicate on the table and keep them based on certain conditions
I'm a complete beginner when using SQL. I have a scenario where I need to delete the duplicates if it does not meet a condition below.
IF a duplicate is found, check if the subscriber key starts with 003 or 001 or 00Q;
if true, then keep all duplicates;
if any of the subscriberkey does not meet the condition, then delete all duplicates.
Example table:



emailAddress
subscriberKey




test@test.com
0035656


test@test.com
0015623


test@test.com
sdfsdfd


t1@test.com
0018956


t1@test.com
00Q4522


xxx@test.com
abcdef



result should be:



emailAddress
subscriberKey




t1@test.com
0018956


t1@test.com
00Q4522


xxx@test.com
abcdef



I'm having a hard time visualizing how to approach this. I thought about grouping them first to check if there's a duplicate then I'm stumped on how to check for the subscriber key.
    DELETE EmailAddress, SubscriberID, Status, SubscriberKey 
    FROM [getting duplicates] t1
    WHERE EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 
         FROM [getting duplicates] As t2 
         WHERE t1.EmailAddress = t2.EmailAddress
         AND (t2.SubscriberKey  NOT Like '003%' OR t2.SubscriberKey NOT Like  '001%' OR t2.SubscriberKey NOT Like  '00Q%' ) OR t2.Status = 'unsubscribed'
         HAVING Count(*) > 1
    ) 

Any thoughts or suggestions that can point me to the right direction will be very helpful.
Thank you very much.

I've added a row to your sample table, so as to have a row that is no duplicate and to show how to go about it.

I, too, would aggregate per email address, then check for each email address whether it is one with more than one entry and whether there exists an enty with an undesired key. Thus I get the set of email addresses that we want to delete. The check for undesired keys is done with conditional aggregation (CASE expression inside aggregation function).
delete from mytable 
where emailaddress in
(
  select emailaddress
  from mytable
  group by emailaddress
  having count(*) > 1 -- duplicate
  and count(case when left(subscriberkey) not in ('001', '003', '00Q') then 1 end) > 0 -- at least one undesired key 
);


This works! I have additional knowledge too. I didn't know that you can use conditional statements when it comes to queries. Thank you :)
